# Select the default language according the domain name

Tags: javascript, symfony, next.js

I want to select the default language of a website according the domain, for example :

[www.test.fr](http://www.test.fr) --> default language is french

[www.test.de](http://www.test.de) --> default language is german

...

So how can I do that?

the application is developed using next.js and the backend is symfony 2.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `i18n` config to your `next.config.js` file:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    // These are all the locales you want to support in
    // your application
    locales: ['en-US', 'fr', 'nl-NL'],
    // This is the default locale you want to be used when visiting
    // a non-locale prefixed path e.g. `/hello`
    defaultLocale: 'en-US',
    // This is a list of locale domains and the default locale they
    // should handle (these are only required when setting up domain routing)
    // Note: subdomains must be included in the domain value to be matched e.g. "fr.example.com".
    domains: [
      {
        domain: 'example.com',
        defaultLocale: 'en-US',
      },
      {
        domain: 'example.nl',
        defaultLocale: 'nl-NL',
      },
      {
        domain: 'example.fr',
        defaultLocale: 'fr',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

More info and examples in the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#getting-started).